# Trouble retrieving package.xml components using ant

Tags: deployment, force.com, sandbox, ant, migration-tool

I am running into the error "Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out" when I try to retrieve the components using a package.xml.

I am trying to retrieve all the Apex classes and Triggers ,nothing apart from it. When I check my user record for login history , I do not see any login attempts using force.com migration tool.

I have appended the security token to my password as well. Can anyone throw any pointers what else I have to look for ?

Please find below the package.xml and the build.properties

[image: build.properties]
[image: package.xml]

Comment: Have you tried `https://test.salesforce.com` for the `serverurl` value?

Answer (score -1):

misalignment in password. could you please add Security token after your password.

eg: yourpasswordXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXX-> your token

Comment: have you tried? without trying the above, how can you downgraded me? For Invalid issue, either you may given wrong credentials or wrong instance or my above answer

Comment: I have appended security token to my password, also included in the above screenshot as well